# Google Cloud Speech: Insufficient tokens for quota group

Tags: audio, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I'm getting the following error when I try to process a single 10 minute audio file.  I'm just getting started with Google Cloud products and so I'm the only person accessing this resource.  How could I have exceeded the quota?  The quota is set at its default values and I dont think that I am anywhere near the limits.  Is there another reason for this?
I'm using the `transcribe_async.py` demo code.  The audio files (22MB) are stored in a bucket and being accessed through a `uri` audio source, otherwise the demo code is unchanged.

```
Waiting for server processing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/python-docs-samples-master/speech/api-client/transcribe_async.py", line 116, in <module>
    main(args.speech_file)
  File "/Users/kevin/Downloads/python-docs-samples-master/speech/api-client/transcribe_async.py", line 93, in main
    response = service_request.execute()
  File "/Users/kevin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/operations/596739883637256586?alt=json returned "Insufficient tokens for quota group and limit 'Default_GroupCLIENT_PROJECT-100s' of service 'speech.googleapis.com', using the limit by ID '764086051850'.">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having this problem too.  I'm still trying to understand more about how the GCP credentials generally, but in the meantime I think I've figured out enough to make this work.  I'm also using the example Python scripts.  I followed the instructions at [this page](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files).

The gist of it is:

1. Create a "private key" using the Credentials page of the Google Cloud Console.  It's really more than simply a "key", it's a (JSON) config file with many values such as 'type', 'project_id', and so forth.
2. Download that file and save it somewhere.  I put mine in the `~/.config/gcloud/` folder which seems to also have a lot of relevant config files.
3. Set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point at that file, i.e. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json`

There's also a way to do this from within the code shown on that page, but the environment variable route made more sense for me.

It seems that the process above sets the "default" credentials, and in the example code those are fetched on [line 39](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api-client/transcribe_async.py#L39).

There's additional documentation on the Google sites, I found the one on [Google Cloud Storage authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) to be the most useful so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get error because use Application Default Credentials specified by the command "gcloud auth application-default login". Try to create a Service Account for your project. Save the JSON key in the private folder. Then specify the path to the key, like this:

> ```
> var speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
>   keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
> });
> ```

It's important, your project should be enabled billing. To enable billing, you can activate the Free Trial period

Comment: Thank you.  But how is this used?  I'm working with `transcribe_async.py`.  I tried adding this to the JSON object, but it is not being accepted.  The syntax looks like JavaScript.  How would this be used with Python?

Comment: Sorry for not being more complete.  I do already have a proper server credential in JSON form.  I put it in the `~/.config/gcloud folder` and assumed it could be accessed.